# How to make condition to be optional in MySQL, so that if my condition becomes wrong, query should be execute

Tags: mysql

I have to MySQL tables named "QUIZ" and "CHAPTER" as shown below

**QUIZ**

```
qid | quizname | chapterid
=========================
1   | quiz1    |     0
-------------------------
2   | quiz3    |     1
-------------------------
3   | quiz3    |     2
-------------------------
```

**CHAPTER:**

```
chapterid | chaptername  
=========================
1         | chpter1    
-------------------------
2         | chpter2    
-------------------------
3         | chpter3    
-------------------------
```

Now i want to get details of quiz from QUIZ table, **where quizid=1**.
My sql query is

```
"SELECT quiz.qid, quiz.quizname, chapter.chaptername from quiz, chapter
 where quiz.chapterid=chapter.chapterid and quiz.qid=1"
```

but i get no result.
So please explain me that what can be a problem?

Comment: Maybe this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html is what you are searching for

Answer (score 2):

You can see that chapterid 0 is not present in the Chapter table and that is why the query does not return anything (rightfully so). 
If you do want it to return the quizname from quiz table, even if chapter id is not valid, then you should use a left outer join. Like this :

```
SELECT quiz.qid, quiz.quizname, chapter.chaptername 
from quiz 
left outer join chapter On quiz.chapterid=chapter.chapterid 
Where quiz.qid=1
```

Obviously, the chaptername returned will be null. (Note : I put the code above to show you the left outer join idea. Check out any MySql-specific syntax I might have overlooked).

Comment: May I request you to mark the question as resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

since the chapterId associate with qid = 1 is 0 which is not matching with any other row from another table so your query will return empty records
so you better change AND to OR and try to run

```
"SELECT quiz.qid, quiz.quizname, chapter.chaptername from quiz, chapter
 where quiz.chapterid=chapter.chapterid OR quiz.qid=1"
```

with join

```
select quiz.qid,quiz.quizname,chapter.chaptername from quiz left outer join chapter On quiz.chapterid = chapter.chapterid
```

Comment: yes sir i get it, But even if chapterid is 0 or is not matching with any other row from another table, other details like quizid, quizname should be return, and at place of chaptername there should be "-" or " " will be return. but result should be return.So how can it possible?

Comment: then in that case you have to use join in your query